# problems in importing styles for react-alice-carousel

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use react-alice-carousel,
And in the section of How To Use, It said something like this.
Style import

SCSS

```
@import "react-alice-carousel/src/alice-carousel.scss";
```

CSS

```
@import "react-alice-carousel/lib/alice-carousel.css";
```

Webpack

```
@import "react-alice-carousel/lib/alice-carousel.css";
```

And I am unable to import these files in my local project and so I am not getting the desired outcome.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I'm unable to import these files in my project and due to this I am not getting any display for the carousel.

Comment: unable to import these files...  what is the exact error displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have the wrong `.scss` file path. It should be:

`@import "react-alice-carousel/lib/scss/alice-carousel.scss";`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `node-sass` you'll probably need to import the css file.  I'd recommend importing it in your top level css file.  Which would be `index.css` if you're using `create-react-app`.